# no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::basic_string<char>' and 'double') c++

Tags: c++, oop

```
double vitesse();
string description();
string toString()
{
    return nom + " : " + description() + "\nvitesse : " + vitesse() + ", poids : " + poids;
}
```

this code is part of class I'm testing, and whene i try to compile it the error in the title pops up `return nom + " : " + description() + "\nvitesse : " + vitesse() + ", poids : " + poids;` in this line and i can't understand why?

Comment: `vitesse` returns a `double`, not a `string` so you need to convert that to a string if you want to combine them.

Comment: *and i can't understand why?* -- If you are coming from a Java background, C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the function `vitesse()` returns a `double` value, which can't be concatenated as-is with strings. I believe if you replace `vitesse()` in the return value with `to_string(vitesse())`, it would work.